# include parent array from the same document. Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents, like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c763335eabaf70627249465"),
    "permissions" : [ 
        "adminCompany"
    ],
    "city" : "890",
    "companyName" : "qwe",
    "country" : "890",
    "county" : "890",
    "email" : "varadi83gabor@gmail.com",
    "headquarters" : null,
    "modifyed" : null,
    "name" : "qwe",
    "nickname" : null,
    "password" : "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",
    "postalCode" : "890",
    "registered" : ISODate("2019-02-27T06:50:29.035Z"),
    "shops" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c797074b2e01c38ac55b796"),
            "city" : "Nagymaros",
            "country" : "Hungary",
            "county" : "Pesyt",
            "currency" : "HUF",
            "district" : null,
            "language" : null,
            "name" : "Piknik",
            "phone" : "123123123",
            "places" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c79714fb2e01c2ee3196a63"),
                    "name" : "terasz",
                    "products" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5c797162b2e01c2ee3196a65"),
                            "active" : true,
                            "added" : null,
                            "description" : "borocska baszod",
                            "modified" : null,
                            "name" : "bor",
                            "taxPercentage" : 27,
                            "unit" : "liter",
                            "unitPrice" : 1500
                        }
                    ],
                    "qrcodes" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5c79715cb2e01c2ee3196a64"),
                            "name" : "asztal1"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c79718cb2e01c52afb050f9"),
                    "name" : "emelet",
                    "products" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5c79719db2e01c52afb050fb"),
                            "active" : true,
                            "added" : null,
                            "description" : "sorocske baszod",
                            "modified" : null,
                            "name" : "sor",
                            "taxPercentage" : 27,
                            "unit" : "korso",
                            "unitPrice" : 500
                        }, 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5c7971deb2e01c52afb050fd"),
                            "active" : true,
                            "added" : null,
                            "description" : "szaros viz",
                            "modified" : null,
                            "name" : "teodora",
                            "taxPercentage" : 27,
                            "unit" : "liter",
                            "unitPrice" : 1000
                        }
                    ],
                    "qrcodes" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5c797195b2e01c52afb050fa"),
                            "name" : "qr1"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7a20ef2fa7fa847633bb39"),
                    "name" : "Addf",
                    "products" : [],
                    "qrcodes" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5c7a20f92fa7fa847633bb3a"),
                            "name" : "Kisfaszom"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "postalCode" : "123",
            "region" : "Közép-Magyarország",
            "staffs" : [ 
                {
                    "permissions" : [ 
                        "staffServing"
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7a6248b2e01c744f8b67b5"),
                    "email" : "varadi83gabor@gmail.com",
                    "modifyed" : null,
                    "name" : "12e12e",
                    "nickname" : "qweqwe",
                    "password" : "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",
                    "registered" : ISODate("2019-03-02T11:00:25.956Z"),
                    "status" : "active"
                }, 
                {
                    "permissions" : [ 
                        "staffFront", 
                        "staffCourier", 
                        "staffManager", 
                        "staffServing"
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7a629fb2e01c744f8b67b7"),
                    "email" : "varadi83gabor@gmail.com",
                    "modifyed" : null,
                    "name" : "Kis Ferenc",
                    "nickname" : "123123",
                    "password" : "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",
                    "registered" : ISODate("2019-03-02T11:01:52.235Z"),
                    "status" : "active"
                }
            ],
            "status" : "active",
            "street" : "qewqweqwe",
            "streetNumber" : 123123
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c7aa611b2e01c5565f70aff"),
            "city" : "Budapest",
            "country" : "Hungary",
            "county" : "pest",
            "currency" : "HUF",
            "district" : "VI. kerület",
            "language" : null,
            "name" : "Kiado kocsma",
            "phone" : "123123",
            "places" : [],
            "postalCode" : "1066",
            "region" : "Közép-Magyarország",
            "staffs" : [],
            "status" : "active",
            "street" : "Jokai",
            "streetNumber" : 19
        }
    ],
    "status" : "inactive",
    "street" : "890",
    "streetNumber" : "890",
    "taxNumber" : "890",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I have to find one of the staff from company.shops.staffs array by _id and I also want to include all the available shops from company to the output document.

here is the aggregation I try:

```
this.companyManager.aggregate([
                {"$match": {"shops.staffs._id": body.staffId}},
                {"$unwind": "$shops"},
                {"$unwind": "$shops.staffs"},
                {"$match": {"shops.staffs._id": body.staffId}},
                {"$project": {_id: "$shops.staffs._id", shops: "$shops", staff: "$staffs"}},

            ], function(error, result:Null<Array<Dynamic>>) {
                trace(error);
                trace(result);
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    callback({status: Status.ERROR, data: result, error: "not found staff"});
                } else {
                    callback({status: (error == null) ? Status.SUCCESS : Status.ERROR, data: result[0].staff, error: error});
                }
            });
```

but this is just include the shop of the staff where work.

How can I generate oputput doc like this one?:

```
{"staff":<staffData>,"shops":[shopsArray]}
```

//////EDITED//////
So I need to find a staff from the shops.staff array and all shops from the company.shops array, and put it to document like this:

```
{
    "staff": {
        "permissions": [
            "staffServing"
        ],
        "_id": ObjectId("5c7a6248b2e01c744f8b67b5"),
        "email": "varadi83gabor@gmail.com",
        "modifyed": null,
        "name": "12e12e",
        "nickname": "qweqwe",
        "password": "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",
        "registered": ISODate("2019-03-02T11:00:25.956Z"),
        "status": "active"
    },
    "shops": [<SHOPS DOCUMENTS>]
}
```

I hope this is clear now, thanks!

Comment: Really not that clear what you are trying to do here. Are you possibly trying to get all the details of "all shops" where a person ( or persons ) work? Grouped "per person" as it were? Would you then want all the details? i.e including all the other people working at each shop. Does not really help that `"$staffs"` is not even a valid field, so it's not even clear what you expect your current code to produce either.

Comment: I want to to find one staff by id: (done) and include all the shop is available in company. I need this to move the selected staff to another shop.

Comment: Can you just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54967921/edit) with additional details and then leave a comment to notify when you have completed that. That's better than trying to write a long story ( or present data ) in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

I have used `map` and `filter`

```
db.companyManager.aggregate([
    {
        '$addFields': {
            'staff': {
                '$filter': {
                    'input': {
                        '$map': {
                            'input': '$shops', 
                            'as': 'shop', 
                            'in': {
                                'staffs': {
                                    '$filter': {
                                        'input': '$$shop.staffs', 
                                        'as': 'staff', 
                                        'cond': {
                                            '$eq': [
                                                '$$staff._id', body.staffId
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    'as': 'staff', 
                    'cond': {
                        '$gt': [
                            {
                                '$size': '$$staff.staffs'
                            }, 0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$staff"},
    {$project:  {_id:0, staff: "$staff.staffs", shops: "$shops"} },
    {$unwind: "$staff"}
])
```